# Google Api Address Validation in REST mode and googlemaps 4.10.0 (python) give different results: How can I get the same result?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

In this example in REST mode, the postal code has been replaced:

```
curl -X POST -d '{
    "address": {
        "regionCode": "IT",
        "addressLines": ["Via Verdi 17 20030 Cesate"]
    }
}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
"https://addressvalidation.googleapis.com/v1:validateAddress?key=..."

...

{
    "componentName": {
        "text": "20031"
    },
    "componentType": "postal_code",
    "confirmationLevel": "CONFIRMED",
    "replaced": true
}
```

I am using Python `googlemaps` 4.10.0 package to confirm the postal code:

```
import config_loader
import googlemaps

config = config_loader.Config()

# Create a client of the googleMaps client library
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=config.api_key)

key='VIA VERDI 17,20030,CESATE'

address_validation_result = gmaps.addressvalidation(key)

print(address_validation_result["result"]["address"]["postalAddress"])
print(address_validation_result["result"]["address"]["addressComponents"])
```

I have got the following output:

```
{'regionCode': 'IT', 'languageCode': 'it', 'postalCode': '20030', 'administrativeArea': 'MI', 'locality': 'Cesate', 'addressLines': ['Via Giuseppe Verdi, 17']}
[{'componentName': {'text': 'Via Giuseppe Verdi', 'languageCode': 'it'}, 'componentType': 'route', 'confirmationLevel': 'CONFIRMED'}, {'componentName': {'text': '17'}, 'componentType': 'street_number', 'confirmationLevel': 'UNCONFIRMED_BUT_PLAUSIBLE'}, {'componentName': {'text': '20030'}, 'componentType': 'postal_code', 'confirmationLevel': 'CONFIRMED'}, {'componentName': {'text': 'Cesate', 'languageCode': 'it'}, 'componentType': 'locality', 'confirmationLevel': 'CONFIRMED'}, {'componentName': {'text': 'MI', 'languageCode': 'it'}, 'componentType': 'administrative_area_level_2', 'confirmationLevel': 'CONFIRMED', 'inferred': True}, {'componentName': {'text': 'Cesate', 'languageCode': 'it'}, 'componentType': 'administrative_area_level_3', 'confirmationLevel': 'CONFIRMED', 'inferred': True}, {'componentName': {'text': 'Italia', 'languageCode': 'it'}, 'componentType': 'country', 'confirmationLevel': 'CONFIRMED', 'inferred': True}]
```

Can anyone help me understand why I got two different results?